# How does audacity play text

Tags: audacity

I thought that if importing raw data in audacity it had to be in hexi pairs. But it was pointed out to me elsewhere that actually audacity can import any text.

So what is audacity doing to the text file to make it playable?

And for bonus points: is that process in some way the "perfect" transformation of text to sound; i.e. are there other equally valid ways of playing text :) ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not ideal.  It isn't doing anything to the text file other than reading it incorrectly.  RAW data is expecting binary data, not text.  But text is an encoded as binary data, so the file actually is a binary file.  The encoding of the text file impacts how the binary data is formed, but reading it as a RAW audio file is really completely inaccurate and will only use a small subset of values since the main alphabet is a small portion of most text encoding systems, so most binary values will be unused.